# Secure a variable in android

Tags: android

I have an integer variable in my application which I want to save for future use. Depending on it's value (like when the value is 0), I will be blocking a functionality of my app and will be requesting an in app purchase for the same.

If I save it anywhere in internal storage, it'll be flushed after Clearing Data, and if I save it in external storage, the path of the file can be easily found by decompiling the code, and server based solutions are out of my scope.

I know that a full proof security is almost impossible, and you might be thinking of downvoting my question, but I really need some advise from experts like you so that I can at least achieve maximum security, so that I can somehow figure out that the variable's value has been tampered and in that case I'll reset it to zero.

Comment: If it is per user, use firebase realtime database, if it is for all users then use firebase remote config

Comment: clearing data will clear all persistent data, the only thing you left with the server integration you can communicate with server when application start and validate your conditions.

Comment: yes, the value will be different for different users.... So according to you firebase realtime database is the best option right @archLucifer ?

Comment: @Pavan yes. and it is quite simple to set up

Comment: But Firbase Realtime Databse states that the data is synced across multiple users. So if a user sets some value to that variable, is it that the same value will be reflected to other users as well? coz the value should be different for different users

Comment: Each user will be a child with a uuid, and you query by child

Comment: But to fetch the data in Firebase Realtime Database, a listener is there which triggers the method `onDataChange()` whenever there is a change in data, but I need just a simple method that I can call anytime to fetch the my data... Is this thing feasible in Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to secure the variable without the server implementation, so in order to achieve your functionality you can perform following steps.

- First you need to check the In App Purchase product status - If it's purchased by user then you need to unlock the next functionality.
- If user has not purchased or subscribe using in app purchase then you need to lock the next functionality.

Comment: Subscriptions and In-App Purchases API -
 https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#subscriptions_api_overview
This should help.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to protect stored data from reading you can use encryption to store something in the file and then use it in your application. Yes, somebody can find a path to your data, but it would be hard to read it. Also it's impossible to modify data, only corrupt.

On the other hand, it's better to use internal storage or preferences. And yes, data actually should be cleared by clearing application data. You should create default value at the start of your application, if requeired field is missing, and store it. Nothing should remains on device if user delete application\clears data.